# wso2 configure a Secondary User Stores using read-only LDAP

Tags: ldap, wso2

I hava configured a Secondary User Stroes useing read-only LDAP,the Results as shown below
[image]
[image]

I have seen the users which is configured in LDAP Server,the users as shown below

[image]

But i can't use the ldap account to login and i confirm that my account password is correct
the wso2carbon.log show the log is

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2020-06-22 11:11:18,584]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} - Login failed. Unauthorized login attempt 'SHAOJIE.FENG[-1234]' at [2020-06-22 11:11:18,583+0800]
```

so I don't know where the problem is,anyone can provide some advices?

Comment: Hi 冯绍杰,  can you please let us know which product version you are using for this scenario? Is this WSO2 API Manager 3.1.0?

Comment: @TharikaMadurapperuma yes, the version is 3.1.0

Comment: Hi 冯绍杰, Your configurations seem to be correct. But are you trying to login to the carbon console with this user? If yes, then you will not be able to login with this user if he does not have the admin permissions. Or else, are you trying to login to Publisher or Developer Portal?